# User controls and Viewstate

Tags: asp.net, controls, viewstate, radcombobox

I have a user control where I display a telerik radgrid and some textboxes and radcombo boxes.  My radcombo boxes lose view state on postbacks.  The text boxes and the grid maintain their state, but not the combo boxes.  Any clues why?  I read somewhere that databound controls on user controls don't maintan their state on postbacks.  This seems ludacris and besides, my databound radgrid doesn't "lose" it's data.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Steve

Comment: I have not used RAD controls, but did you check with telerik support on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding these user controls dynamically (in code-behind) or statically (aspx markup)?

If you are creating them dynamically, make sure they are recreated on every postback, and make sure that is occurs no later than `OnInit()`. This way the viewstate can be restored.